# Converting BeautifulSoup object into list to extract data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From the following two lines of python code I get the following html output which belongs to class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'

```
site_link = soup.find_all('a', string='Aberdeen')[0]
row = site_link.findParent('td').findParent('tr').findAll('td')

 <html><body><p>[</p><td><a href="../networks/site-info?site_id=ABD">Aberdeen</a><br/>
<a class="smalltext" href="https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/assets/graphs/ABD_weekly_m.png">Timeseries Graph</a></td>,
 <td class="center"><span class="bg_low2 bold">48 (2 Low)</span></td>,
 <td class="center"><span class="bg_low1 bold">4 (1 Low)</span></td>,
 <td class="center"><span title="Not Measured">n/m</span></td>,
 <td class="center"><span class="bg_low1 bold">2 (1 Low)</span></td>,
 <td class="center"><span class="bg_low1 bold">6 (1 Low)
 </span>
</td>,
 <td>19/08/2017<br/>17:00:00</td>]</body></html>
```

How can I make it into a list whereby I can extract items so that, e.g. where my list is called mylist:

```
>>>print(mylist[1].text)
48 (2 Low)
```

Comment: Yes I've got it figured out now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `tag.find_all`:

```
mylist = soup.find_all('span', class_='bg_low2 bold')
```

Now, `mylist` contains all your `span` tags, and you can access the i<sup>th</sup> `span`'s data with `mylist[i].text`.

Comment: Thanks, although how can I access all the items/elements e.g. the time (the last element) which doesn't have _class='bg_low2 bold'

Comment: @Paulos `soup.find_all('span')`

Comment: @JonClements Oops. Thanks. :)